# Как в WiX скопировать msi log файл в пользовательскую папку?

Tags: windowsinstaller, wix

По умолчанию вовремя установки MSI пакета файл лога пишется в `%TEMP%` папку. Значение полного пути этого файла находиться в свойстве `MsiLogFileLocation`.

Как при любом (кроме краха процесса установки) окончании установки скопировать лог файл в заданную папку?

Answer (score 0):

Можно установить новое значение в `MsiLogFileLocation` или скопировать файл лога при помощи `CustomAction`.

Но нужно учитывать, что в этом случае часть данных будет потеряно так, как запись в лог будет производиться до установления значения в `MsiLogFileLocation` и после копирования.

Чтобы лог полностью был записан в другой файл нужно устанавливать путь к этому файлу до запуска `msiexec.exe`, т.е. использовать ключ `/L` [командно строки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/command-line-options).

```
msiexec Product.msi /L SetupProduct.log
```